# ASP.Net MVC Visual Studio Deploy "Mark as IIS application on destination"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using the Visual Studio "Publish Web" screen to publish my ASP.Net to my web site.
I has worked fine up until recently with the "Mark as IIS application on destination" box checked.

I just recently added a new project to the solution to handle a specific portion of the work, and then added this project as a reference to the ASP.Net project. The problem is now the publish will not work unless I un-check the box "Mark as IIS application on destination".

It seems dangerous to me to publish without this box checked. Does anyone know why adding this new project to the solution caused this issue and how to fix it?

This is the error I get:

> Web deployment task failed.((1/20/2012 6:50:00 PM) An error occurred
>   when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (1/20/2012 6:50:00 PM) An error occurred when the request was
>   processed on the remote computer. Unable to perform the operation.
>   Please contact your server administrator to check authorization and
>   delegation settings.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the publish will not work"?

Comment: The "publish web" Screen in Visual Studio http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/20yh9f1b.aspx

Comment: Does it give an error message?

Comment: Yes; I updated the questions. Its pretty cryptic. The server has not changed so I am pretty sure the problem has to be something in the visual studio solution / upload process.

Comment: Indeed that is pretty cryptic and really tough to diagnose.  I would start by going through the error log on both machines and seeing if there was any additional info

Comment: I only have access to the development machine :( Do you know is publishing with this checkbox off a bad thing? Or is it harmless? I just want to make sure my source etc is not web accessible / less secure because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the account on the server expired.

Comment: I'm running into the same error. w.donahue, what account is it that expired?